# Need to add a value to session of wordpress / woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, session, woocommerce, tracking

I need to include affiliate tracking. The pixeltracking (order id and order total) is already working by using the hook woocommerce_thankyou, but I need to add another ID which is passed via URL.

The customer is being forwarded to my shop using something like this: "http://myshop.com/?bid=123"

I need to keep the value of "bid" in the session until checkout. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// define woocommerce_init callback
function action_woocommerce_init(  ) 
{
    if( function_exists('WC') && isset($_GET["bid"]) ){
        WC()->session->set( 'bid', $_GET["bid"]);
    }
};

// add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'action_woocommerce_init', 10, 0 );
```